# BigDecimal - to use new or valueOf

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I came across two ways of getting BigDecimal object out of a double d.

1. `new BigDecimal(d)`
2. `BigDecimal.valueOf(d)`

Which would be a better approach? Would `valueOf` create a new object?

In general (not just BigDecimal), what is recommended - new or valueOf?

Comment: In general, valueOf is preferred (because it can avoid making new objects by reusing "popular" instances), but in the case of BigDecimals and double, unfortunately, the two methods produce different results, so you have to choose which one you need.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Those are two separate questions: "What should I use for `BigDecimal`?" and "What do I do in general?"

For `BigDecimal`: this is a bit tricky, because they **don't do the same thing**. [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29) will use the [*canonical `String` representation*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) of the `double` value passed in to instantiate the `BigDecimal` object. In other words: The value of the `BigDecimal` object will be what you see when you do `System.out.println(d)`.

If you use [`new BigDecimal(d)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) however, then the `BigDecimal` will try to represent the `double` value *as accurately as possible*. This will *usually* result in a lot more digits being stored than you want. Strictly speaking, it's more correct than `valueOf()`, but it's a lot less intuitive.

There's a nice explanation of this in the JavaDoc:

> The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing `new BigDecimal(0.1)` in Java creates a `BigDecimal` which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a `double` (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, appearances notwithstanding.

In general, *if the result is the same* (i.e. not in the case of `BigDecimal`, but in most other cases), then `valueOf()` should be preferred: it can do caching of common values (as seen on [`Integer.valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29)) and it can even change the caching behaviour without the caller having to be changed. `new` will *always* instantiate a new value, even if not necessary (best example: `new Boolean(true)` vs. `Boolean.valueOf(true)`).

Comment: This also explains my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685705/android-java-rounding-error-cant-understand-why#15685784

Comment: @Joachim, it wasn't clear. Is `new BigDecimal()` better than `BigDecimal.valueOf()`?

Comment: @ryvantage: if one where strictly better than the other then there would be no need for both and my answer would be much shorter. They don't do the same thing, so you can't rank them at like that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, ok sorry I should've been more specific. Would you mind giving an example of when `new BigDecimal()` would be preferred and an example of when `BigDecimal.valueOf()` would be preferred?

Comment: @ryvantage: Compare the results of `new BigDecimal(1.0/30.0);` and `BigDecimal.valueOf(1.0/30.0)`.  See which result is actually closer to the numerical fraction 1/30.

Comment: _"valueOf() should be preferred: it can do caching of common values"_ I just looked at the source code for `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` and it does NOT do any sort of caching. It just has one line: `return new BigDecimal(Double.toString(val));` and that has to always create a new object. (I believed the lie too, so I'm stumped myself.)

Comment: This has bitten me multiple times.  When I have a double that displays as .3065 I expect my BigDecimal of it to also be .3065...  Not so when using "new"!  I'm now just defaulting to using valueOf (unless I specifically require the other) as the vast majority of my work depends on exact matches of precision (current industry requirements).

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: ironically the "new" one actually matches the input double more closely and it's the toString output that's "cheating" by cutting off digits that are correct but not necessary to distinguish one double value from the next.

Comment: @JoachimSauer  Yeah, what I really *want* to do is remove all doubles and convert entirely to BigDecimal, but that'd be a massive undertaking for an application whose EOL date is approaching.  :-)

Comment: but new BigDecimal(0.99) became 0.989999..., which return me a wrong result

Comment: @BeeingJk: yes, and I explain in detail in this answer why that is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 62):

If you are using your `BigDecimal` objects to store currency values, then I strongly recommend that you do **NOT** involve any double values anywhere in their calculations.

As stated in another answer, there are known accuracy issues with double values and these will come back to haunt you big time.

Once you get past that, the answer to your question is simple. Always use the constructor method with the String value as the argument to the constructor, as there is no `valueOf` method for `String`.

If you want proof, try the following:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(0.01);
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("0.01");
System.out.println("bd1 = " + bd1);
System.out.println("bd2 = " + bd2);
```

You'll get the following output:

```
bd1 = 0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375
bd2 = 0.01
```

See also this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400032/can-we-use-double-to-store-monetary-fields-and-use-bigdecimal-for-arithmetic/8497607#8497607)

Comment: Totally agree, best practice.

Comment: println result of BigDecimal.valueOf(0.01)) is 0.01

Answer (score 8):

Basically valueOf(double val) just does this:

`return new BigDecimal(Double.toString(val));`

Therefore -> yep, a new object will be created :).

In general I think it depends upon your coding style. I would not mixure valueOf and "new", if both are the same outcome.

Comment: Technically true, **but**: it'll make a **huge** difference. `valueOf()` has the more *intuitive* behaviour, while `new BigDecimal(d)` has the more *correct* one. Try both and see the difference.

Comment: Technically false. 'new' always keyword always creates a new object while the javadoc does not tell if valueOf will return always a new object or not. It does not, not always. It has some values in cache so `new BigDecimal(1) != new BigDecimal(1)` but `BigDecimal.valueOf(1) == BigDecimal.valueOf(1)`

Comment: @user: yes, but since `BigDecimal` is immutable it should be treated the same way that the primitive wrappers (`Integer`, `Byte`, ...) and `String` are treated: object identity *should not matter* to your code, only the *value* should matter.

Comment: @Joachim Right but that internal cache is there for a reason. Too many not needed equal instances of BigDecimal are not a good thing to have. And I was answering to Dr, He said "a new object will be created"

Comment: @user: yes, that's why I said that `valueOf()` should *generally* be preferred. But note that `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` doesn't do any caching (and it probably wouldn't be worth it, either).

Comment: @Joachim Right, it is for valueOf(long). As commented in the source code it is planned to do it with double too but you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Please use:

```java
new BigDecimal(String val) or BigDecimal.valueOf(double val);
```

Don't use:

```java
new BigDecimal(double val);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Foreword

Why are we having these discussions about floating-point type, numbers & arithmetic? Simple. We count in base 10, but the machine count in base 2.

#### BigDecimal - Need for an exact representation (not approximation)

If you are using `BigDecimal`, this means that you want an exact representation of `0.1` and other negative powers of ten (usually you would be dealing with money or arithmetic involving decimals).

#### Double means trouble (where BigDecimal is concerned)

Then, if you are finding yourself having to manipulate `double`(or float) values using `BigDecimal`, then you are in double trouble, because it is impossible to represent `0.1` as a double in base 2. The machine "stores" doubles([IEEE-754 standard for floating-point arithmetic](https://standards.ieee.org/ieee/754/6210/)) as base 2. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) is a good write-up of what's really happening if you are interested.). [Duncan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9713581/4982691) illustrates what i am trying to say, of what to do and not do.

Any programming language that you think can store 0.1 accurately is actually not. It is just an approximation.

```
System.out.println(0.1d);
//Prints 0.1 or so you think ;-)

//If you are not convinced, try this:
double x = 1.1; double y = 1.0;
if (x-y == 0.1) {// print true } else {// print false}

//or perhaps this:
double amount1 = 2.15;
double amount2 = 1.10;
System.out.println("Difference: " + (amount1 - amount2));
```

#### Examples

```
  double smallD = 0.0001;
  double smallDNoScientificNotation = 0.001; //>= 10E-3
  double normalD = 10.345678;
  double bigDNoScientificNotation = 1234567.123456789; //<=10E7 
  double bigD = 56_789_123_456_789.123456789;

  //double
  System.out.println(smallD); //1.0E-4, computerized scientific notation, this is how Double toString works
  System.out.println(smallDNoScientificNotation); //0.001, OK
  System.out.println(normalD); //10.345678, OK
  System.out.println(bigDNoScientificNotation); //1234567.123456789, OK
  System.out.println(bigD); //5.6789123456789125E13, computerized scientific notation, this is how Double toString works
  
  //new BigDecimal(double): not OK, don't use! Attempting to representing the base-2 representation as accurately as possible
  System.out.println(new BigDecimal(smallD)); //0.000100000000000000004792173602385929598312941379845142364501953125
  System.out.println(new BigDecimal(smallDNoScientificNotation)); //0.001000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375
  System.out.println(new BigDecimal(normalD)); //10.34567799999999948568074614740908145904541015625
  System.out.println(new BigDecimal(bigDNoScientificNotation)); //1234567.12345678894780576229095458984375
  System.out.println(new BigDecimal(bigD)); //56789123456789.125
  
  //BigDecimal.valueOf (Dont use if the range is >= 10E-3, >= 10E7), under the hood it's using Double.toString
  System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(smallD)); //0.00010 - notice the extra 0, stemming from 1.0E-4
  System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(smallDNoScientificNotation)); //0.001
  System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(normalD)); //10.345678
  System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(bigDNoScientificNotation)); //1234567.123456789
  System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(bigD)); //56789123456789.125 //loss of accuracy
```

**Computerized scientific notation** - more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29).

#### BONUS 1 - Pitfalls

[Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/four-common-pitfalls-of-the-bigdecimal-class-and-how-to-avoid-them)

#### BONUS 2 - Effective Java 3rd edition (Joshua Bloch)

**Item 60: Avoid float or double if exact answers are required**

The float and double types are particularly ill-suited for monetary calculations because it is impossible to represent 0.1 (or any other negative power of ten) as a float or double exactly.
:
There are, however, two disadvantages to using BigDecimal: it's a lot less convenient than using a primitive arithmetic type, and it's a lot slower. The latter disadvantage is irrelevant if you're solving a single short problem, but the former may annoy you.
:
An alternative to using BigDecimal is to use int or long, depending on the amounts involved, and to keep track of the decimal point yourself. In this example, the obvious approach is to do all computation in cents.

#### Extra reading for the mathematically inclined ;-)

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)