# Java BigDecimal Rounding Error

Tags: java, android, rounding, bigdecimal

I have the following function that is used to round a double value in Java:

```
public static double round(double d, int decimalPlace) {

    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(d));
    bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

As input, this function is receiving these values:

```
double d = 7.3149999999999995;
int decimalPlace = 2
```

But, when the function returns, the value returned is 7.31, instead of 7.32.
I searched on the docs to see why the bd.SetScale is with that behavior, but with no success.

Does anybody could me explain why is this happening?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what happens if you give it `7.314999995` instead? maybe the `5` gets lost

Comment: Why is that surprising? It's not exactly halfway between 7.31 and 7.32, so why would it round up to 7.32?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I´m using BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP, so, it´s expected to round to 7.32, I guess..

Comment: @regisxp: Only if the value is half way between 7.31 and 7.32 though... and 7.3149999999999995 *isn't* half-way between the two. Try it with 7.315 and it will do what you expect.

Comment: @JonSkeet: oh hah, that's a good point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does anybody could me explain why is this happening?

It's obeying the documented behaviour :) From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29):

> If the scale is reduced by the operation, the unscaled value must be divided (rather than multiplied), and the value may be changed; in this case, the specified rounding mode is applied to the division.

And for [`RoundingMode.HALF_UP`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP):

> Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up.

Now 7.3149999999999995 *isn't* equidistant to both 7.31 and 7.32 - it's closer to 7.31, so that's the result.

The difference between `HALF_UP` and `HALF_DOWN` would only be seen if the original value were exactly 7.315, i.e. half way between the two.

As an aside, to make sure you get *exactly* the number you'd expect to start with, I'd suggest using a `String`. For example:

```
double d = 0.1;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
```

isn't the same as:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("0.1");
```

Converting from `double` to `BigDecimal` is *usually* a sign that you've got something wrong, and you should be using one type consistently throughout.

Comment: @Anshu: I'm hoping that anyone with a similar question in the future would search for HALF_UP or HALF_DOWN, find this and compare their situation with this one...

Comment: @Anshu thanks a lot for your explanation. The problem is that, another languages, like C#, round this same value to 7.32 and I need to maintain the same logic here... So, I tested all RoundingModes and none of then worked as I expected...

Comment: Hey! The explanation is from Jon!

Comment: @regisxp: Please post the code you're using in .NET... you need to work out *exactly* what's going on. Note my point about converting from `double` to `BigDecimal` being basically a bad idea...

Comment: @JonSkeet, after reading carefully, I noticed that the problem wasn´t the Rounding itself... Is the double´s intrinsic imprecision, that was widely discussed... On C#, decimal x =  (decimal)7 * (decimal)(1 - 0.05) is 7.315, that when rounded HALF_UP, if 7.32. On Java, using doubles, 7d * (1 - 0.05) is 7.314999999... So, rewriting using BigDecimals (new BigDecimal(7.7d).multiply(new BigDecimal(1).subtract(new BigDecimal(0.05d))).doubleValue()) returs me the 'correct' value. Is there any advice to make the previous method, using BigDecimal, clear? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @regisxp: The problem is the previous method took a `double`, which raises big flashing warning lights. I would back away from that decision to start with.

Comment: I would strongly agree with Jon that if you are even remotely serious about your decimal arithmetic (especially with currency) you should *NEVER* use double and *ALWAYS* use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

ROUND_HALF_UP: Rounding mode to round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up.

In your example, the nearest neighbor is: 7.31 because 4 in 7.314 is closer to 0 than 10.  To prove this, change 7.314... to 7.315....

Look at the different rounding modes to provide the behavior you want.

Comment: Also, you can instantiate BigDecimal as BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d) instead of converting d to a string in the BigDecimal constructor.

Comment: No. If you involve doubles anywhere in `BigDecimal` instantions you will introduce [rounding issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186204/bigdecimal-to-use-new-or-valueof/9713581).