# Android: java rounding error. Can't understand why?

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal, rounding

Can anybody explain why on Earth these "same" expressions returns different values?

```
(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(131.7d))).multiply(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(0.95d))).doubleValue() = 125.115

(new BigDecimal(               131.7d )).multiply(new BigDecimal(               0.95d )).doubleValue() = 125.11499999999998
```

What BigDecimal is doing different between them?

Comment: for those voting to close as duplicate, the questions are similar but are not duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the API documentation, you will find taht `String.valueOf(dobule)` uses `Double.toString(double)` to format the value. It's perhaps not obvious, but `Double.toString(double)` rounds the value, before formatting it as a string:

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a?
>   There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and
>   beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to
>   uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type
>   double. That is, suppose that x is the exact mathematical value
>   represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for
>   a finite nonzero argument d. Then d must be the double value nearest
>   to x; or if two double values are equally close to x, then d must be
>   one of them and the least significant bit of the significand of d must
>   be 0.

The result of this is that `String.valueOf(131.7d)` will return the string "131.7" even if the exact value of the argument is 131.69999999999998863131622783839702606201171875. The reason for this is that decimal fractions cannot always be represented exactly using binary fractions (as used with floats and doubles).

So, new `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(131.7))` will create a BigDecimal with the exact value 131.7. `new BigDecimal(131.7)` will create a BigDecimal with the exact value 131.69999999999998863131622783839702606201171875.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
BigDecimal(double val)
          Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value.
```

versus

```
BigDecimal(String val)
          Translates the string representation of a BigDecimal into a BigDecimal.
```

These are in fact not the same thing.  In the `double` constructor it is using a floating point number (which are inherently inaccurate).  In the `String` constructor it is taking the exact value you supplied and **not** doing a floating point conversion.  So this does in fact mean that the constructors above are not the "same" expressions

Comment: So, there's no other way to get the "correct" value of this calculation (131.7 * 0.95 = 125.115) than convert value to string before passing it to BigDecimal? This seems so strange to me!

Comment: I don't understand why 2 constructors with same input values, returns 2 different results. If Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(131.7d)) == 131.7d, why should BigDecimal returns different values? It doesn't make any sense to me!

Comment: Hmm, you are actually not answering Christian's question here, since he starts with 131.7d and 0.95d in both cases. The reason for the difference he observes is not because of the different BigDecimal constructors, but that String.valueOf(dobule) is indirectly rounding the argument before converting to a string and not returning a string with the exact value of the argument.