# Follow-up to BigDecimal new or valueof

Tags: java, bigdecimal

This question is a follow up to the question ([BigDecimal - to use new or valueOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186204/bigdecimal-to-use-new-or-valueof)) and its accepted answer.

To reiterate the question and answer for convenience:

`BigDecimal` has two methods:

```
double d = 0.1;
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(d);
BigDecimal bd2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
```

Which one is better? The answer shows that these methods do not produce the same result:

```
System.out.println(bd1);
System.out.println(bd2);
```

displays:

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
0.1
```

In the answer, the answerer states :

> In general, if the result is the same (i.e. not in the case of `BigDecimal`, but in most other cases), then `valueOf()` should be preferred: it can do caching of common values (as seen on `Integer.valueOf()`) and it can even change the caching behaviour without the caller having to be changed. new will always instantiate a new value, even if not necessary (best example: `new Boolean(true)` vs. `Boolean.valueOf(true)`).

My question is: can we get some practical examples of when, specifically, we should use `BigDecimal.valueOf()` and when we should use `new BigDecimal()` ?? The answerer says "use `valueOf()` if the result is the same" but that doesn't help us to know when to use it (if ever?) for `BigDecimal`.

Specifically, which is preferable:

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

or

```
0.1
```

? And why?

Comment: Well which result do you *want*? They do different things, in clearly documented ways.

Comment: How do you know which one you _want_? That's the core of the question. Would one ever be better than the other and why?

Comment: Better in which sense? Speed or correctness? `0.1` isn't precisely representable in two's complement floating point.

Comment: @ryvantage Which one do you expect? Without any information, I would guess you want `0.1` but only you know what your requirements are.

Comment: The one that's "better" is the one that leads to the entire program giving you the desired results.  And we don't know what that program is supposed to do.

Comment: The purpose of the question was to extract possible scenarios as to why one would be preferable over the other. I have no exact specifications, this is really more of a theory question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, any time you convert from a `double` to `BigDecimal` you should take a step back and ask yourself whether you're really doing the right thing to start with. For example, if you've done this by parsing from a `String` to a `double`, then you should probably go straight from a `String` to a `BigDecimal`. I'm generally wary of this conversion, as it usually suggests someone is using an inappropriate type elsewhere.

Beyond that, they do different things: the constructor gives a `BigDecimal` which represents the exact same number as the `double`; `valueOf` gives a `BigDecimal` which represents the number given by the `double` value's canonical string representation. They're simply different things, and you should know which one you want when you try to use one.

Given that I'd try to avoid getting into this situation to start with, it's hard to give examples of when each is more appropriate, but if you've *unavoidably* converting text to a `double`, then lost the original text, but want to get back to that value, then using `valueOf` is *likely* to give you a better result. If you've performed a bunch of arithmetic operations on `double` values, then the constructor *might* be more appropriate. But it's really very context-sensitive, and as I say in most cases I'd probably choose a redesign rather than picking either option.

Comment: I can accept "this generally isn't a valid scenario" as an answer. `BigDecimal` is good for holding a `double` resulting from arithmetic, but how often do you have an **original** double that didn't result from arthimetic of integers? I guess I can't think of one situation... So yeah great point.

Comment: @ryvantage: No, it's not really "good for holding a `double` resulting from arithmetic" - `double` is!

Comment: The truth is that when I started programming I used `float` for everything; even for storing currency values (in dollars)... even for currency arithmetic! In the end, my calculations were always a few cents off. My clients didn't complain, but I wasn't happy. I've been learning a lot through the years and I've slowly been converting all of my code to use `BigDecimal` and to store currency as `int`s, but it's difficult to remember to convert to dollars for calculations and views so what I have now is a big jumbled mess of `double`s for some things, `int`s for others, and `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @ryvantage: Why not just store the currency as `BigDecimal`? All your currency arithmetic can be done using `BigDecimal`, so you don't need a jumble at all.

Comment: Anyways, my code used to use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` but I caught wind of that other question and refractored my code to use `new BigDecimal(double)` but then I realized I wasn't sure which is superior. Now I need to re-evaluate everything to see if I need to pass doubles to these `BigDecimal`s at all. But there's a ton of stuff being calculated on these dashboards I build (ratios, sales totals, etc) so it can be hard..

Comment: partly because I don't want to run up the bill on my client fixing my newbie errors.. And, at that, I'll be fixing code I already supposedly "fixed." It gets difficult to explain to the end-user, especically when the numbers are really _only a few pennies off_ which they don't mind (but I do!!).

Comment: Ahh yes! I found a great example of needing to pass a `double` to `BigDecimal`. When you are pulling in from a `ResultSet` using `ResultSet#getDouble("column")`. If you pass that to a `BigDecimal`, you either need to use `valueOf()` or the constructor.

Comment: @ryvantage: Why would you not just use `ResultSet.getBigDecimal` to start with?

Answer (score -1):

Look at the sources of BigDecimal and it is kind of obvious that passing a double into valueOf is less efficient than calling the constructor