# Round a double in Java

Tags: java, floating-point

I have found this great solution for rounding:

```
static Double round(Double d, int precise) {
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(d);
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(precise, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bigDecimal.doubleValue();
}
```

However, the results are confusing:

```
System.out.println(round(2.655d,2)); // -> 2.65
System.out.println(round(1.655d,2)); // -> 1.66
```

Why is it giving this output? I'm using jre 1.7.0_45.

Comment: Can you print the value of `BigDecimal` in the `round` method?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: It's not wrong. That's how [floating point works](http://floating-point-gui.de/). `2.655d` is probably `2.654999...`

Comment: Yea, I wondered what neighbour meant in the java doc. The next internal bit representation or the next string?

Comment: You create a `BigDecimal` from a `double`... That's like trying to make gold from pyrite: it may look like it but that's not it (ie, don't do that, use gold to start with)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You have to replace

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(d);
```

with

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
```

and you will get the expected results:

```
2.66
1.66
```

Explanation from Java API:

**BigDecimal.valueOf(double val)** - uses the double's canonical string representation provided by the Double.toString() method. This is preferred way to convert a double (or float) into a BigDecimal.

**new BigDecimal(double val**) - uses the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value and thus results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: +1, I didn't know that. But you should explain [why](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) that makes a difference.

Comment: @zapl:- I tried to explain that in my answer! Do let me know if i missed anything

Comment: user3301492, You can edit your answer, it looks better if you put it there instead of a comment :) - @RahulTripathi +1 as well, nothing missing, maybe more explanation of string conversion and that the string constructor is then creating a precise representation by not using a normal double as internal representation.

Comment: Let me add that is always better to use `valuesOf` than `new` when dealing with numbers. The reason is that, having `BigDecimal first = new BigDecimal(x)` and `BigDecimal second = new BigDecimal(x)`, `first == second` may output `false`, while using `valueOf` instead of `new` leads to a more consistent behaviour with primitive type (if `first = BigDecimal.valueOf(x)` and `second = BigDecimal.valueOf(x)`, then `first == second` will always be `true`). NOTE: I am not so sure this is valid for `BigDecimal`s, but it lasts for the others `Number`s

Comment: @mardavi actually it is not guaranteed that `valueOf(x) == valueOf(x)` for _any_ of the standard library `Number` types. Current OpenJDK implementations of `Integer` and `Long` cache some commonly-used values (but not all values, as that would cost more in memory than it's worth), but `Float` and `Double` `valueOf` methods just call the constructor. Still I agree that it is best to use `valueOf` in general.

Comment: @MikeFHay, thank you! `Integer` caches to 128 (I think) and that's why `==` works as expected with `new Integer` for integers smaller than 128 (I don't know for negative numbers). However, I didn't know the behavior of `valueOf` is not consistent with `Float` and `Double`

Answer (score 26):

You may try to change your program like this:-

```
static Double round(Double d, int precise) 
{
BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);
bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(precise, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
return bigDecimal.doubleValue();
}
```

**[Sample Ideone](http://ideone.com/sVHWjL)**

```
Success  time: 0.07 memory: 381184 signal:0
Rounded: 2.66
Rounded: 1.66

Success  time: 0.07 memory: 381248 signal:0
Rounded: 2.66
Rounded: 1.66
```

**Reason why you are getting the expected result with `BigDecimal.valueOf` and not with `new BigDecimal`**, in the words of [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186204/bigdecimal-to-use-new-or-valueof/7186298#7186298):

> `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` will use the [canonical String representation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) of the double value passed in to instantiate the BigDecimal object. In other words: The value of the `BigDecimal` object will be what you see when you do `System.out.println(d)`.
>
> If you use `new BigDecimal(d)` however, then the BigDecimal will try to represent the double value as accurately as possible. This will usually result in a lot more digits being stored than you want.

Hence resulting in some **confusion** which you are watching in your program.

From the Java Doc:

> **[BigDecimal.valueOf(double val)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29)** - Translates a double into a BigDecimal, using the double's canonical string representation
> provided by the Double.toString(double) method.
>
> **[new BigDecimal(double val)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29)** -
>
> Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal
> representation of the double's binary floating-point value. The scale
> of the returned BigDecimal is the smallest value such that (10scale ×
> val) is an integer. Notes:
>
> - The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One    might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>   BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1,
>   with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>   0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>   matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>   that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>   0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> - The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable:    writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal
>   which is exactly    equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it
>   is generally    recommended that the String constructor be used in
>   preference to this    one.
> - When a double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal, note that    this constructor provides an exact conversion; it does not give the
>   same result as converting the double to a String using the
>   Double.toString(double) method and then using the BigDecimal(String)
>   constructor. To get that result, use the static valueOf(double)
>   method.

Answer (score 18):

[This test case](http://ideone.com/Hq4TuE) ends up pretty self-explanatory:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println("Rounded: " + round(2.655d,2)); // -> 2.65
    System.out.println("Rounded: " + round(1.655d,2)); // -> 1.66
}

public static Double round(Double d, int precise)
{       
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(d);
    System.out.println("Before round: " + bigDecimal.toPlainString());
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(precise, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("After round: " + bigDecimal.toPlainString());
    return bigDecimal.doubleValue();
}
```

Output:

```
Before round: 2.654999999999999804600747665972448885440826416015625
After round: 2.65
Rounded: 2.65

Before round: 1.6550000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875
After round: 1.66
Rounded: 1.66
```

A dirty hack to fix it would be to [round in two steps](http://ideone.com/OwItNM):

```
static Double round(Double d, int precise)
{
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(d);
    System.out.println("Before round: " + bigDecimal.toPlainString());
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(15, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("Hack round: " + bigDecimal.toPlainString());
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(precise, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println("After round: " + bigDecimal.toPlainString());
    return bigDecimal.doubleValue();
}
```

Here, `15` is a bit under the maximum number of digits a double can represent in base 10. Output:

```
Before round: 2.654999999999999804600747665972448885440826416015625
Hack round: 2.655000000000000
After round: 2.66
Rounded: 2.66

Before round: 1.6550000000000000266453525910037569701671600341796875
Hack round: 1.655000000000000
After round: 1.66
Rounded: 1.66
```

Comment: It seems like a hack, but it's very similar to the process that `valueOf` is using, just more explicit. The conversion to a string does the first rounding.

Answer (score 8):

As said in [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29)

> 1. The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a
>      BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with
>      a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to
>      0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that
>      matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value
>      that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to
>      0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> 2. The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal which
>      is exactly equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, it is
>      generally recommended that the String constructor be used in
>      preference to this one.
> 3. When a double must be used as a source for a BigDecimal, note that this constructor provides an exact conversion; it does not give the
>      same result as converting the double to a String using the
>      Double.toString(double) method and then using the BigDecimal(String)
>      constructor. To get that result, use the static valueOf(double)
>      method.

It's because of cannot represent double value exactly. So you have to use `BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(d);` instead of `BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(d);`

Answer (score 7):

Rounding a `double` resp `Double` in itself does not make much sense, as a `double` datatype **cannot** be rounded (easily, or at all?).

What you are doing is:

1. Take a `Double d` as input and a `int precise` number of digits behind the seperator.
2. Create a `BigDecimal` from that `d`.
3. Round the `BigDecimal` correctly.
4. Return the `double` value of that `BigDecimal`, which has no *rounding* applied to it anymore.

You can go two ways:

1. You can return a `BigDecimal` that represents the rounded double, and later decide what you do with it.
2. You can return a `String` representing the rounded `BigDecimal`.

Either of those ways will make sense.

Comment: +1 as this is the most correct answer. One nitpick though: you certainly can round doubles, in fact they are implicitly rounded - but to binary, digits, not decimal ones.

Answer (score 6):

Decimal numbers can't be represented exactly in double.

So 2.655 ends up being this:
2.65499999999999980460074766597

whereas 1.655 ends up being this:
1.655000000000000026645352591

Comment: Why the first is `499999..` and the second is `500000..`?

Comment: This is not accurate; *some/many* decimal numbers can't be represented.

Comment: Well yes, to be exact. Since double is a binary format, all decimal numbers which have an exact binary representation (which fits into double) can be represented, all others can't. Maroun, take a look at this: http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html