# Convert into 2 decimal points

Tags: java, double, decimal, rounding

I have a code here that calculate a rate for payment. It works however certain value will result in numerous number of decimal points. I want the result to be converted into only 2 decimal point. How do I do this? below is the attached code:

```
            double rateConv=(((new Double(4.4) * transaction.getAmount())/100)+(transaction.getAmount()+new Double(0.30)));     

            System.out.println(rateConv);
            transaction.setCurrencyPsy(rateConv);
            transaction.setUserId(getLoginUserProfile().getUserId());
            transaction.setTransType(WalletConstant.TRANS_DEPOSIT);
            transaction.setIsApproved(false);
            transaction.setCreateDate(new Date());
            transaction.setIsCiTrans(false);
            transDAO.save(transaction,getLoginUserProfile(),getText("email.admin"));
            if(transaction.getDepositType().equals(WalletConstant.DEPOSIT_WIREDTRANSFER)){
                addActionMessage(getText("msg.success.tt"));
            }else{
                addActionMsg(getText("msg.success"));
            }
            transaction = new WalletTransaction();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionErr(getText("Error in system.Please contact system's administrator."));
            return ERROR;
        }       
        execute();
        return "paymount";
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: small advice - you should never use Double or Float for money calculations. Use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: If you are interested in rounding the value, have a look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036885/round-a-double-in-java/22037110#22037110

Comment: I disagree with "never use float or double in money calculations". For example, some compound interest calculations require the use of logarithms, and can be done accurately enough in double. However, BigDecimal is almost always the better choice for money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing what you have asked for

1.

```
         double d = 1.234567;            
         DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
         System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

2.

```
        double d = 1.234567;
        System.out.printf("%1$.2f", d);
```

***but***  I would **never ever** use double for *money values* anyways, I recommend you to take a look at `BigDecimals`

EDIT: look @ Zeeshan ´s answer if you want to convert `Double` to `Big Decimal`.

***but*** the best is to ONLY use `Big Decimal` for money values, then you will never have any rounding issues @ converting.

Answer (score 3):

Use `BigDecimal`

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(doubleValue);
bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
return bd.doubleValue();
```

Here `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` will round towards "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case round up.

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(rateConv));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
double amount = 123;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(df.format(amount));
```