# Separating double according to "." in java

Tags: java, split, double

i have a double number which is "547.123456"

i just want to use this double as "547.1" like only 1 number after "."

How can i do that?

Comment: round it to one decimal or just first decimal?

Comment: You will find this question and answer interesting:- [Round a double in Java]: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036885/round-a-double-in-java/22037280#22037280]

Comment: Do you want to round it or to represent it (print it) that way? You can continue treating it as a double, and use a DecimalFormat to show only one decimal.

Comment: If you want to cut away everything after the first decimal (*not* round it) - trick a little: `d = ((int) (d * 10)) / 10.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use BigDecimal

```
double f=547.123456;
BigDecimal d=new BigDecimal(f);
System.out.print( d.setScale(1, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
```

Comment: +1 this is the only reliable way of ensuring that you are **always** working with `547.1`.

Comment: @skiwi except that the snippet above use a double to create the BigDecimal, in which case the precision is already lost. Only the constructors with String should be used.

Comment: @gizmo the precision is not lost - it is as good as the precision of the original double...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **trancate** a value e.g.

```
  47.12345 -> 47.1
  47.56789 -> 47.5 // <- not 47.6!
```

you can do it via *floor*

```
  double value = 47.123456;
  double result = Math.floor(value * 10.0) / 10.0;
```

If you want to **round** a value e.g.

```
  47.12345 -> 47.1
  47.56789 -> 47.6 // <- not 47.5!
```

you can do it via *round*

```
  double value = 47.123456;
  double result = Math.round(value * 10.0) / 10.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a **String.format**

```
String.format("%.1f",547.123456);
```

This an easiest way i think.

Answer (score 1):

Very easily :)

```
double x = 47.123456;
x = (long)(x*10)/(double)10
```

Comment: Even x+1 can overflow...

Comment: Yes and? Your code can't handle any double larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE, which is a lot less than the largest possible double. Even without the `int` cast, the statement could overflow for very large doubles.

Comment: You should at least cast to long here.

Comment: Now it's in the wrong place. ; P

Comment: @Radiodef - damn me today :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a general solution for every precision, you can specify your own like so:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(<your double>));
```