# Can you combine new (with string constructor) and value of in Bigdecimal

Tags: java, new-operator, bigdecimal, value-of

I saw the following post in stack overflow which is related to my question:

[BigDecimal - to use new or valueOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186204/bigdecimal-to-use-new-or-valueof)

I understand it is recommended to use string constructor for BigDecimal
But my question is once you have defined a bigDecimal with string, can you use that value later using valueof.

Could someone let me know if the following code is valid?

```
BigDecimal tipPercent = new BigDecimal("0.0");
if (tipState == TipSelection.FIFTEEN) {
    tipPercent = BigDecimal.valueOf(FIFTEEN);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean can you recover the `String` that you started with, then sort of: you can turn the `BigDecimal` into a `String` again with `toString()`. So in your case you could call

```
tipPercent.toString()
```

to get a `String` representation of `tipPercent`.

The reason I say "sort of" is that it might not be exactly what you put in, but it'll be equivalent. If you create a `BigDecimal` by passing it `"00"`, you'll get back `"0"`, but it represents the same number.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what Type of variable FIFTEEN is.  valueOf in BigDecimal only works with double or long.

But you can reassign a BigDecimal to another BigDecimal no matter how it was created.