# Round decimal values to two digits after the decimal point

Tags: java, types, floating-point, annotations, data-annotations

What is the best way to get a float value rounded to two decimal digits?

For example, I have `float f1 = 123.9876`.
But I need `123.98`.

Are there any annotations which can do this?

Comment: It depends upon what type of rounding mechanism you want to use?

Comment: yes duplicacy allow

Comment: Is this possible by regular expr?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually with BigDecimal Class

```
float f=123.456778f;
BigDecimal decimalNo=new BigDecimal(f);
decimalNo=decimalNo.setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

decimalNo = 123.45

Comment: Yes, indeed, it will work with BigDecimal. Note that floating point types like float or double will not necessarily succeed. With FP values, one usually doesn't round the *value*, just its *output* (i.e. the conversion to string), using one of the many ways to round output.

Comment: FWIW, it may make sense to use `BigDecimal decimalNo = BigDecimal.valueOf(f);` instead of `new BigDecimal(f);`. But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186204/bigdecimal-to-use-new-or-valueof

Comment: 1).Rounding can be required when any one want to store value in DataBase or file. and    2). Yes you are right, valueOf() will make more sense here.

Comment: even if you store in a DB or file, you are still rounding the output (OK, not just conversion to string -- to anything suitable), not the original value.

Comment: In DB double values are saved in number format not in String. (It is good to convert it in string but rounding is required to original value when it is required, Both options are situational)