# BigDecimal not retaining rounded value when converting to/from float

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I have a function that rounds a float to n number of digits using BigDecimal.setScale

```java
private float roundPrice(float price, int numDigits) {
    BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(price);
    bd = bd.setScale(numDigits, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    float roundedFloat = bd.floatValue();
    return roundedFloat;
}

public void testRoundPrice() {
    float numberToRound = 0.2658f;
    System.out.println(numberToRound);
    float roundedNumber = roundPrice(numberToRound, 5);
    System.out.println(roundedNumber);
    BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(roundedNumber);
    System.out.println(bd);
}
```

Output:

```
0.2658
0.2658
0.26579999923706055
```

How can I prevent BigDecimal from adding all these extra digits at the end of my rounded value?

NOTE: I can't do the following, because I dont have access to the number of digits in the api call function.

```java
System.out.println(bd.setScale(5, RoundingMode.CEILING));
```

Comment: See this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#round(java.math.MathContext)

Comment: Using float at *any point* destroys the benefits of BigDecimal.  To have a consistent number of decimal places, you can't have any floats anywhere.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so if I use a double instead, that should fix it?

Comment: @jeninja A double is a floating-point number, just with a few extra digits. _Use `BigDecimal`_.

Comment: If you want to preserve the exact number `0.2658` then you can do some nasty conversion from Float to String to BigDecimal like so `BigDecimal converted = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(numberToRound));`

Comment: @jeninja: No.  You can't use anything but BigDecimal.  Any float, any double, can ruin the decimal precision.  Don't even use it to initialize the BigDecimal; use a String, e.g. `new BigDecimal("0.2658")`

Comment: It's not `BigDecimal` that's adding the digits.  The problem is that there is no `float` that's exactly 0.2658.  So when you write `0.2658f`, you actually get a float whose value is `0.265799999237060546875`.  If you want something that's exactly 0.2658, you can't use `float`, or `double`.  In that case, `BigDecimal` is the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to modify my program to use BigDecimal as the base type for my property price in my object instead of type float. Although tricky at first it is definitely the cleaner solution in the long run.

```java
public class Order {
    // float price; // old type
    BigDecimal price; // new type
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It’s the other way around. `BigDecimal` is telling you the truth. 0.26579999923706055 is closer to the value that your `float` has got all the time, both before and after rounding. A `float` being a binary rather than a decimal number cannot hold 0.2658 precisely. Actually 0.265799999237060546875 is as close as we can get.

When you print the float, you don’t get the full value. Some rounding occurs, so in spite of the `float` having the aforementioned value, you only see `0.2658`.

When you create a `BigDecimal` from the `float`, you are really first converting to a `double` (because this is what `BigDecimal.valueOf()` accepts). The `double` has the same value as the `float`, but would print as 0.26579999923706055, which is also the value that your `BigDecimal` gets.

If you want a `BigDecimal` having the *printed* value of the `float` rather than the exact value in it or something close, the following may work:

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(roundedNumber));
    System.out.println(bd);
```

Output:

> 0.2658

You may get surprises with other values, though, since a `float` hasn’t got that great of a precision.

**EDIT: you were effectively converting `float` -> `double` -> `String` -> `BigDecimal`.**

These insightful comments by Dawood ibn Kareem got me researching a bit:

> Actually 0.265799999237060546875.
>
> Well, `0.26579999923706055` is the value returned by calling
> `toString` on the `double` value. That's not the same as the number
> actually represented by that `double`. That's why
> `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` doesn't in general return the same value
> as `new BigDecimal(double)`. It's really important to understand the
> difference if you're going to be working with floating point values
> and with `BigDecimal`.

So what really happened:

1. Your `float` internally had the value of 0.265799999237060546875 both before and after rounding.
2. When you are passing your `float` to `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`, you are effectively converting `float` -> `double` -> `String` -> `BigDecimal`.

   - The `double` has the same value as the `float`, 0.265799999237060546875.
   - The conversion to `String` rounds a little bit to `"0.26579999923706055"`.
   - So your `BigDecimal` gets the value of 0.26579999923706055, the value you saw and asked about.

From the documentation of `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`:

> Translates a `double` into a `BigDecimal`, using the `double`'s
> canonical string representation provided by the
> `Double.toString(double)` method.

### Links

- Stack Overflow question: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
- Documentation: [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double))
- Stack Overflow question: [BigDecimal - to use new or valueOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186204/bigdecimal-to-use-new-or-valueof)

Comment: Well, `0.26579999923706055` is the value returned by calling `toString` on the `double` value.  That's not the same as the number actually represented by that `double`.  That's why `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` doesn't in general return the same value as `new BigDecimal(double)`.  It's really important to understand the difference if you're going to be working with floating point values and with `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Indeed you’re right! Today I learned. Thank you. I have edited.

Comment: I've upvoted.  Your edit made the answer much better.