# why Java BigDecimal giving Precision Errors

Tags: java, bigdecimal, arbitrary-precision, fault-tolerance

i am using java big decimal. but still i am not getting expected result..

```
public class DecimalAdjustEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal v1 = new BigDecimal("100");
        BigDecimal v2 = new BigDecimal("75");
        BigDecimal reminder = BigDecimalUtils.divide(v1,v2);
        System.out.println("reminder= "+reminder);
        BigDecimal v1Result = BigDecimalUtils.multiply(reminder,v2);
        System.out.println("v1 Result= "+v1Result);
    }
}
```

Utils class:

```
public class BigDecimalUtils {

    public static final MathContext DEFAULT_MATH_CONTEXT = new MathContext(34, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

    public static BigDecimal multiply(BigDecimal value1, BigDecimal value2) {
        return value1.multiply(value2,DEFAULT_MATH_CONTEXT);
    }
    
    public static BigDecimal divide(BigDecimal value1, BigDecimal value2) {
        return value1.divide(value2,DEFAULT_MATH_CONTEXT);
    }
    
    public static BigDecimal add(BigDecimal value1, BigDecimal value2) {
        return  value1.add(value2,DEFAULT_MATH_CONTEXT);
    }

    public static BigDecimal subtract(BigDecimal value1, BigDecimal value2) {
        return value1.subtract(value2,DEFAULT_MATH_CONTEXT);
    }

}
```

output:

```
reminder= 1.333333333333333333333333333333333
v1 Result= 99.99999999999999999999999999999998
```

here v1 Result should be 100 right.

but why it is giving wrong one. how to handle these problems.
i cannot use more than 34 digits precision. and i do not want rounding. please suggest a solution..
consider i have huge application, no of arthimatic calculations going on. please suggest a feasible solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigDecimal - to use new or valueOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186204/bigdecimal-to-use-new-or-valueof)

Comment: BigDecimal uses decimal representation. It **can not** represent 1.333... exactly, hence the results you are getting. You need to develop rules for rounding

Comment: BigDecimal gives you decimal arithmetic, not exact arithmetic. If you want exact rational arithmetic, you can find open source implementations of that.

Comment: *"Here v1 Result should be 100 right."* - Ermm, no it shouldn't.  You have misunderstood the specification of `BigDecimal`.  Specifically, using `MathContext(34, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`as the context is telling the arithmetic operations (`divide`, `add` and `subtract`) to >>round<< the result to 34 decimal digits after the decimal point.

Comment: How to handle this scenario. I want to maintain precision and accurate results. Please provide code

Comment: Apply scale and round or add tolerance which is best way. And can we handle it globally in Utils class? Instead of writing it in service layers

Comment: Ask your expert stake holders (accountants,  scientists, etc.) how to handle such numbers. They make such decisions/policies, not programmers.